# Using libpcap with Scala

Tags: scala, pcap, libpcap

What's the best way to use libpcap with Scala? I need to capture from live network devices, so it will most likely need a native binding.

I've found a couple like JPcap and JNetPcap but nothing particularly for Scala...

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4):

Since the libraries run on JVM already there is no need for an additional wrapper for Scala. Just pick the best library and [pimp it to your needs](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766).

JNetPcap seems like the most updated one here.

Comment: As I'm new to Scala I was hoping to find a wrapper that wouldn't require me to figure out how to get the Java libraries to inter-operate. I suppose it's not difficult if you know Scala, but being new to it, it's an extra challenge I could do without right now :)

Comment: Well it's quite simple once you've imported scala.collection.JavaConverters._ to convert collections .asJava and .asScala. If I were to write a marginal library, such as these are, I believe I would still consider using java to write them. Both because it is so simple to use in scala, but also to have a larger user and contributor base.